# Struts 1: How to set <html:multibox /> value using form bean?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I would like to have the value of my multibox to be set dynamically from the form. I'm using a `<display:table />` tag to show a list in my form in a table however, I have checboxes on every row on the table which I would like the `value` and `disabled` attributes set depending on the object in the list that corresponds with that row in the table. This is what I'm currently doing.

```
<display:table  name="sessionScope.SearchForm.companyDevices" requestURI="my/action.jspa">
        <display:column>
                <html:multibox property="selectedDevices" 
value="${macAddress}" <!-- HERE -->
disabled="${isAssigned}"/> <!-- AND HERE -->
        </display:column>
        <display:column property="macAddress" title="Mac Address" />
        <display:column property="vendor" title="Vendor"/>
        <display:column property="model" title="Model"/>
        <display:column property="deviceStatus" title="Device Status" />

</display:table>
```

As you can see a column property uses the same `macAddress` bean value and it displays the macAddress there successfully, however in the multibox it doesn't set the value to the macAddress for some reason. Same goes for the `disabled` attribute.

I can't seem to identify what is wrong. How do I set dynamic values for multiboxes in a `display:table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way. I replaced the multibox tag above with

```
 <display:table  name="sessionScope.SearchForm.companyDevices" requestURI="my/action.jspa" id="device"> <!-- ID ATTRIBUTE ADDED -->

<html:multibox property="selectedDevices"><bean:write name="searchForm" property="companyDevices[${row_rowNum - 1}].macAddress" /></html:multibox>
```

`rowNum` is an implicitly created variable in struts and to retrieve the row Number for a particular row. To identify a row an Id needs to be assigned. By setting the id to 'device' in the `display:table` I use `device_rowNum` (the implicitly created variable from the combination of my the `id` attribute and `rowNum`) get a row's particular number which is associated with its position in the list to be able to retrieve the value that I want.